# Push notifications to active directory groups even if offline

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, push-notification

I have a WPF applications that runs on 2'000 PCs (xp, vista, win 7, win 8),
and the only thing it does is to show new notifications taken from a main server.

At the moment everything works trough pooling and it is hard for the server to handle that load.
I'm now required to provide the same service to another customer which has 4'000 PC,
so pooling is no longer an option.

The customer wants also to be able to specify which Active Directory group should receive the notification,
and every notification must been received by the client even if offline at the time (it will receive it when back online).
Security is not an issue.

I'm searching for the best architecture suited for the task,
this is what I have considered so far:

1) WCF-MSMQ: discarded, it requires msmq active on every client machine.

2) WCF-nettcpbinding publish-subscribe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254(v=vs.110).aspx):
It would be perfect but how I'm supposed to handle different groups?
Should I check the group of the user and based on that subscribe it to a different topic?

3) Keep all clients always connected to the server:
on connect the client sends it's Domain Name to the server,
the server associate a connection to a user and keep looping trough all the connections while sending notification when available for that user.
I'm not sure how many connections I'm able to always keep opened.
Should I use WCF or just make my own sockets system? The logic is pretty basic but it needs to be available on multiple windows platforms with different .NET version.

Do I still need the clients to send back an ACK when received a notification? Or I can just trust the TCP ACK?
Any suggestions will be much appriciated.